# merging rows in SQL LISTAGG

Tags: sql, merge, listagg

I am trying to merge rows in sql using LISTAGG but, getting the error message not a group by function

```
select
tbc.idattribute,
tbc.idclient,
tbc.idclientattribute,
tbc.idattributetype,
tbl.vcdescription,
LISTAGG(tb.vclongdescription, '; ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY tbc.idclient) " test_consent",
person_id
from
tbclientattribute tbc, tblookupheader tbl, tbclient, tblookupdetail tb
where tbc.idattributetype = tbl.idlookupheader (+)
and tbclient.idclient = tbc.idclient (+)
and tbc.idattribute = tb.idlookupdetail(+)
group by person_id
order by person_id
```

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what merging you mean, but for that select statement, you need to include all selected vairables in the GROUP BY for it to work. Something like this:

```
select
tbc.idattribute,
tbc.idclient,
tbc.idclientattribute,
tbc.idattributetype,
tbl.vcdescription,
LISTAGG(tb.vclongdescription, '; ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY tbc.idclient) " test_consent",
person_id
from
tbclientattribute tbc, tblookupheader tbl, tbclient, tblookupdetail tb
where tbc.idattributetype = tbl.idlookupheader (+)
and tbclient.idclient = tbc.idclient (+)
and tbc.idattribute = tb.idlookupdetail(+)
group by person_id, tbc.idattribute,tbc.idclient,tbc.idclientattribute,tbc.idattributetype,tbl.vcdescription
order by person_id;
```